# ES6 Dynamic Module Import Express Routes

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I'm attempting to dynamically import files containing routes for an Express server using ES6 notation instead of associating each route with a file like this:

```
import router from './routes/test.mjs'
app.use('/api/create/test', router)
```

In my main file `App.js` I have a function which aims to return the matching :entity import from the query parameters:

```
async function routingFunct(req, res, next){
    let entity=req.params.entity
    const { default: dynamicImport } = await import(`./routes/${entity}.mjs`);
    return dynamicImport
}

app.use('/api/create/:entity', routingFunct)
```

In my `./routes/test.mjs` file I have

```
router.get('/', async function(req, res)
{ 
    ...await logic here...
})
export default router
```

When sending a get request to the endpoint `/api/create/test`, the page simply hangs forever. What am I doing wrong here? How can I tell my Express server to run the middleware in `App.js` then run the logic in the matching `:entity.mjs`?

Comment: Express middlewares don't support `return`ing new routers. At best, you'd need to do `dynamicImport(req, res, next)` (although I'm not sure whether express passes some extra internal state to nested routeres)